# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex, ssl

We are calling external system webservice from Salesforce. the webservice exposed are internet We have created stub from the WSDL. It is a SOAP based call. But while calling the service,  We are getting error 'java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present'.

Comment: If the endpoint URL of the external system uses HTTPS, then a CA signed SSL certificate must be present on the other end and must match the domain name.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that could be wrong here.

1) If you're using HTTPS for the Endpoint URL, the other system must have a CA signed SSL certificate

2) Make sure you've added the endpoint URL in the Remote Site Settings in salesforce

3) If you're using Salesforce CA signed certificate, make sure you specify the cert name in your class ([example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_client_certs_soap.htm)) and you upload the cert file on the other server.

> EDIT: I've found some good examples for different types of integration
>   using SSL. Hope this helps.
>
> [Making authenticated web service callouts from Salesforce](http://krishhari.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/making-authenticated-web-service-callouts-from-salesforce-to-ibm-cast-iron-using-sslcertificatespart-i/)
>
> [Making Authenticated Web Service Callouts Using Two-Way SSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If i understand you correctly we need to follow the below steps
1) Create 'CA-Signed' Certificate in Salesforce.
2) Download Certificate Signing Request.
3) We need to send it across the downloaded certificate to the team working on external system webservices for signing the certificate.
4) Once the signed certificate is received,we need to upload signed certificate in our Salesforce.
5) request.setClientCertificateName('xxxxx') should be set in our code

Comment: It would be great if you can help us know the steps for signing the certificate which needs to done at the external system

Comment: Are you using IP address instead of dns name?

Comment: I've updated the answer and provided link with some examples.