# Two Way SSL Configuration With Tomcat 6

Tags: community, java, ssl

I am trying to configure SSL with Tomcat I have following all the steps of the configuration on tomcat server and Force. com side. 
I have follow the below link-

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL

Both the server and client are configured but getting following error-

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
```

Second I have no clarification about how client and server will communicate, how will they identify each others identity.

Thanks,
VikaS

Comment: Here is [SFSE link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37210/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-subject-alternative-names-present) about the same issue.